# UITextfield pointer to another UITextfield not updating text

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uitextfield

I have a class which contains multiple textfields. Two of these textfields allow the user to enter a password and password confirmation.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextfield *password;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextfield *passwordConfirmation;
```

I have now created a new class that handles displaying your password strength. The class contains 2 properties password and password confirmation (as well as other code which handles the checking of the password and displaying the strength).

```
@interface PasswordChangeView : UIView

 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextfield *password;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextfield *passwordConfirmation;
```

Inside the first class I create a property of PasswordChangeView and set the two properties to the original properties.

```
 @property (nonatomic weak) IBOutlet PasswordChangeView *passwordChangeView;

 self.password = self.passwordChangeView.password;
 self.passwordConfirmation = self.passwordChangeView.passwordConfirmation;
```

I have checked in the debugger and the pointers are the same.

However when I enter text into: self.passwordChangeView.password, the text in self.password remains the same.

I would have thought that because they both point to the same object, changing the text in one UITextfield would update the other one.

If the question is not clear enough, please let me know and I will edit straight away. Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a UIView containing the two UITextFields password and passwordConfirmation? You can directly put them to the UIViewController you are being implemented, isn't it?

Comment: I should clarify. The new view has more functionality. It contains a uiview to display the strength of the password as well as code that calls into a library that handles the logic for checking if how strong a password is.

Answer (score 0):

Because the pointers are the same, they now both point to the same thing. If you set `*b = *a`, then changing the text of `*b` will only cause the outlet of `*a` to update.

You need to set the text of both at the same time, without changing their pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out the code was wrong in a different place. I have left an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was having issues elsewhere in the code which made it seem like the text wasn't being updated.

I can confirm that by changing the text of:

`self.passwordChangeView.password;` or

```
self.passwordChangeView.passwordConfirmation;
```

was indeed changing the text of the other 2 text fields that were pointing to these.